# How to update multiple chrome extensions in the same time?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a few almost equal extensions on chrome store (some of configs are different, images, names..). Extensions have same code with mentioned differences. 
How can I automatically update all extensions if I make some hotfix? Currently, I need to update each separately which is time consuming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Webstore Publishing API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index#Items) to programmatically upload updates and publish them.

There's [an official guide](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) on using the API.

Short version:

- You need to create a Google Developers Console project and enable the API for it.
- You need to take the Client ID / secret from the Developer Console.
- You need to obtain an access token through OAuth with the above.
- Using this token, you can upload updates and publish them with a REST API.